# Program Template to Fuse Loop

Tags: c++, templates, for-loop, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

How to fuse for loop with template?

Method 1 fuses the three loops.

Method 2 seems not. (or the compiler has already done it?)

[gcc god bolt for method 1](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g62,options:'-O3',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4QHsDOAXATggQwFsA%2BAKFElkVWwE8AHBAfTwJG03LOwSIagFeqcNiQARBA2wALcuCjhkAN3Qg4SKOnQMAFKIBUSOCCIAaJIaQR0MML1wXRSTCABeCAJQBvMkn%2BW9sZIALwu7sgAtBJSsgDcfgEAZui4uv42dg4A2nAAuqFIAAwJAWUBmfYIuLkFKMamtaXl/gDUrZU5%2BT6JLVo6KJLSMkjRAIwkuibm1rZVjq4ens3%2BAL5k67z8gsIo8mCKYCpqGv0MKEWTztPZeU5BndW392KLXr5lOHAAXN%2BZ2CgUAAiYBAhLrMjOIjsMC6VTqHpla6NAphbwAJjMAGYzOjVitAmJHjVUUhvEUzBSivjekhaQB6ekAWQQsnQGjGtJSaWcIEKJUsqCQY3RcSQ7RAnhc2B%2Bf1sYkBILBDIMDOZrJk7KQ6NpZxQWMm0wsxIsWOWtIM9JVapZbI0WK5qV0xOyRVJJVpZRdbqFNzdBLK7W9eURLSQ3OdcxyY3dAbDLpjvsaMbjLSDUaeMdDYeSTpd6NjnpzFQzNQLSaI2QLqeL6ayTwLPSLxelsv%2BitBceb5XWOd7AX7/ktGyAAA)),filterAsm:(colouriseAsm:!t,commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3)

[gcc god bolt for method 2](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g62,options:'-O3',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4QHsDOAXATggQwFsA%2BAKFElkVWwE8AHBAfTwJG03LOwSIagFeqcNiQARBA2wALcuCjhkAN3Qg4SKOnQMAFKIBUSOCCIAaJIaQR0MML1wXRSTCABeCAJQBvMkn%2BW9sZIALwu7sgAtBJSsgDcfgEAZui4uv42dg4A2nAAuqFIAAwJAWUBmfYIuLkFKMamtaXl/gDUrZU5%2BT6JLVo6KJLSMkjRAIwkuibm1rZVjq4ens3%2BAL5k67z8gsIo8mCKYCpqGv0MKEWTztPZeU5BndW392KLXr5lOHAAXN%2BZ2CgUAAiYBAhLrMjOIjsMC6VTqHpla6NAphbwAJjMAGYzOjVitAmJHjVUUhvEUzBSivjepptOcsZNphZiRYsctaQB6Ay0lJpYnZIqkkq0soCoWoBpEQV5AlldrivKIlpIPm6AVjYVylUaupS7Ka7UtBVzHKa5Uq5KpdWmp7orWiy0VW01e2Sm72o1Ok1ZO1K3yOp0ubA/P62AHA0HawPldaWuMBBP%2BAycjZAAA%3D)),filterAsm:(colouriseAsm:!t,commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3)

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <int Depth>
inline void loop(int* dim, int* counter, int size){
    int d = size - Depth;
    for(  counter[d] = 0;
          counter[d] < dim[d];
        ++counter[d]){
        loop<Depth - 1>(dim, counter,size);
    }
}
template <>
inline void loop<0>(int dim[], int counter[], int size){
    std::cout<<"#";
}

int main(void){
    int dim[] = {2,3,2};
    int counter[] = {0,0,0};

    //Method 1
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; ++i) std::cout <<"#";
    /*
    //Method 2
    loop<3>(dim, counter, 3);
    */
}
```

Comment: clang inlines and unrolls all loops with method 2, gcc seems to miss the optimisation opportunity.

Comment: clang seems to completely unroll the loops. i want to fuse the loops because in actual usage, the array is quite large. may be the compiler will behave differently if I use larger array?

Comment: of course. It will do what is 'optimal'. It has to be said, that since IO is involved (in this example) unrolling doesn't really optimise anything.